# Entity framework not singular-izing classes

Tags: entity-framework, naming-conventions, entity-framework-5

I have around 30-35 tables in database. But when I am using EF 5 I generate the classes and also have the singular/plural option ticked (as you can see in the image below), all the classes don't get singular-ized!

[image]

[image]

Any solution, or am i doing something wrong?
Targeting framework 4.0 and tried with 4.5 as well.

Regards

Comment: This is happening for my current database, seems something wrong in my database.
Have tried in a new database, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found out later that Entity Framework does not singularize/pluralize tables with underscores, so I had to rename the tables and works fine now.

Comment: Can you provide any more info on why this is?